# C# Issue with adding data from XML to combobox

Tags: c#, xml, combobox

I'm fairly new to XML files and I am trying to read from a XML and input some values from a XML and store them in a Combobox.  I have looked over many examples and have not found one close enough to figure this out.  I have managed read from the XML file and input the data into the Combobox, but for some reason everything gets added to one line.

Here is what the XML file looks like.

```xml
    <menus>
      <addMaterialForm>
        <filamentType>
          <Type>ABS</Type>
          <Type>PETG</Type>
          <Type>PLA</Type>    
        </filamentType>
      </addMaterialForm>
    </menus>
```

Here is my C# code:

```cs
        private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(Globals.xmlFilePath);

            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        filamentBox.Items.Add(child.InnerText);
                    }
                }
          }
```

For some reason all of the inner text is added together and this is the result I get.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKH4X.jpg)

I'm really scratching my head here and any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retrieving all type values at once from "filamentType" element, you need to go one more level down.

Another approach would be to use `XDocument.Descendants` to retrieve all values of particular element.

`ComboBox` has `DataSource` property. Retrieve collection of types from xml file and set this collection to the `DataSource` property.

```
var document = XDocument.Load(Globals.xmlFilePath);
var types = document.Descendants("Type").Select(element => element.Value).ToList();

filamentBox.DataSource = types;
```

For "one liner" fans :)

```
filamentBox.DataSource = XDocument.Load(Globals.xmlFilePath)
    .Descendants("Type")
    .Select(element => element.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome this worked out perfect.  I knew I was missing something simple!  After this I just added the list to the combobox.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well you havent used an XPath to reach the right Parent (filamentType) where the required items exists. Hence Inner text gives you all Node values.

Use xpath like:

```
//menus/addMaterialForm/filamentType
```

to reach the right Parent XmlNode.
Then loop through all children and add to combobox.